# Docker, nginx, nginx proxy not redirecting to the right container

Tags: docker, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm setting up some containers in my Ubuntu server. I've created two simple images this way:

Dockerfile: `static-site`

```
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY ./site/ /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Dockerfile: `static-content`

```
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY ./assets/ /usr/share/nginx/html
```

*The Dockerfiles are in different location*

Until here no problem at all. I've installed nginx-proxy and used the `VIRTUAL_HOST` to run them:

```
 docker run -d -p 80 -e VIRTUAL_HOST=mysite.com static-site
 docker run -d -p 80 -e VIRTUAL_HOST=static.mysite.com static-content
```

The result is that whatever address I put in the browser it always redirect me to `mysite.com`.

What am I doing wrong?

Also, I have a DNS record like this:

```
*.mysite.com    86400   A   0   xxx.xxx.xx.xx (the ip of mysite.com)
```

Could it be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cant bind two containers to the same port ("80"). Most probably that the second container is dead (you can verify this by running `docker ps`). or it is running with automatically assigned ports

```
docker ps --format " {{.Image}} ==> {{.Ports}}"
nginx ==> 0.0.0.0:32769->80/tcp
nginx ==> 0.0.0.0:32768->80/tcp
```

To fix this issue you either use different ports for the containers and configure your DNS to be linked to a load balancer (so you can configure the destination port) or you switch to use single Nginx with multiple server definitions.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY ./site/ /usr/share/nginx/site_html
COPY ./assets/ /usr/share/nginx/assets_html
COPY ./site.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Nginx Config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  mysite.com;

    root /usr/share/nginx/site_html;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  static.mysite.com;

    root /usr/share/nginx/static_html;
}
```